# Gas dryer connection adapter brass to steel nut

Tags: dryer, natural-gas, connectors

I recently got a dryer and the installer did not have the right adapter to connect my gas line to the dryer. The yellow gas line installed in the previous dryer is still there and has a steel nut at the dryer end(the nut that is used to make the connection). The installer said I should be able to get the adapter at a hardware store as the one he had was small. I however cannot find a galvanized steel 1/2 inch flare and 3/8 FIP adapter. I did get this which is brass. https://www.homedepot.com/p/Everbilt-1-2-in-Flare-x-3-8-in-FIP-Brass-Adapter-Fitting-801379/207176728#product-overview . I think this should work but not sure of any issues given the adapter is brass while the nut to which the flare end connects to is steel. Should both of these be the same material? That is steel adapter to steel female nut?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question. Your thinking of galvanic reaction of the two dissimilar metals. I don't believe it will be a problem and no reaction will occur as no standing water is present.